# Reloading lorenwest's NodeJS config module

Tags: node.js, vorpal.js

I need to reload the config lorenwests config module in multiple files if someone sends the `reload` command. To achieve that, I followed [this issue](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/34#issuecomment-9040733) but it didn't work out for me.

I'm working on NodeJS version 8.5 if that helps.

These are my code files:

**main.js**

```
let vorpal = require("vorpal")();
let { childConfig } = require("./child.js");

vorpal
    .command("reload", "Reloads the config", {})
    .action((args, callback) => {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve("config")];
        vorpal.log("reloaded config");
        callback();
    });

vorpal
    .command("config <item>", "Shows an item from the config", {})
    .action((args, callback) => {
        vorpal.log("main config: `" + require("config").get(args.item) + "`, child config: `" + childConfig(args.item) + "`");
        callback();
    });

vorpal
    .delimiter("test$")
    .show();
```

**child.js**

```
exports.childConfig = function (cfg) {
    return require("config").get(cfg);
}
```

**config/default.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "hello": "test",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is delete the data cached by require, but that may not be enough. What you need is also to read the data again.

Seems like lorenwest has a long history with the reload functionnality, and specifically discourage this, as it is supposed to be used for deployment configuration, not runtime configuration. (https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/188)

What you may do is try to reread the file with lorenwest (even though I don t see where you are using it), and manually refresh the configuration variable.